# Unity resolution problem, mesh has holes when zooming out

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, rendering, resolution

I have a server which renders a mesh using OpenGL with a custom frame buffer. In my fragment shader I write the `gl_primitiveID` into an output variable. Afterwards I call `glReadPixels` to read the IDs out. Then I know which triangles were rendered (and are therefore visible) and I send all those triangles to a client which runs on Unity. On this client I add the vertex and index data to a `GameObject` and it renders it without a problem. I get the exact same rendering result in Unity as I got with OpenGL, unless I start to zoom out.

Here are pictures of the mesh rendered with Unity:
[image: Normal mesh]

[image: Some triangles are missing]

My first thought was that I have different resolutions, but this is not the case. I have 1920*1080 on both server and client. I use the same view and projection matrix from the client on my server, so this also shouldn't be the problem. What could be cause of this error?

**In case you need to see some of the code I wrote.**

Here is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is my fragment shader code:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out int primitiveID;

void main(void)
{ 
   primitiveID = gl_PrimitiveID + 1; // +1 because the first primitive is 0
}
```

and here is my `getVisibleTriangles` method:

```
std::set<int> getVisibleTriangles() {
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, &pixels[0]);

    std::set<int> visibleTriangles;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelsLength; i += 4) {
        int id = * (int*) &pixels[i];
        if (id != 0) {
            visibleTriangles.insert(id-1); // id 0 is NO_PRIMITIVE
        }
    }
    return visibleTriangles;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of anti-aliasing enabled?  On the server that might affect which triangle is grabbed per-pixel.

Comment: If OpenGL does not do any anti-aliasing by default there shouldn't be, but I will also check this, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok so I checked this and multisampling is not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my god, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake.
After all it *WAS* a resolution problem.

I didn't call `gl_Viewport` (only when resizing the window). Apparently when creating a window with `glfwCreateWindow` GLFW creates the window but since the parameters are only hints and not hard constraints (as it is stated here: [glfw reference](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344)) it is possible that those are not exactly fulfilled. Since I have passed a desired size of 1920*1080 (which is also my resolution) apparently the drawing area did not actually get the size of 1920*1080, because there is also some space needed for the menu etc. So it is rendered with a lower resolution (to be exact, it was 1920*1061) on the server which results in missing triangles on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into the shader details for this problem, are you sure that the problem doesn't lie with the way the zoom out functionality has been implemented in Unity? It's just a hunch since I have seen it in older projects, but if the zoom in/out functionality works by actually moving the camera then the movement of the clipping planes will create those "holes" when the mesh surfaces go outside the range. Although the placement of some of those holes in the shared image makes me doubt that this is the case, but you never know.

If this happens to be the way the zoom function works then you can confirm this by looking at the editor mode while zooming out. It will display the position of the clipping planes of the camera in relation to the mesh.

Comment: The way I am currently doing it is, I send the camera matrix and the projection matrix from Unity to my server. The view matrix I use is `Camera.main.worldToCameraMatrix` and the projection matrix is `Camera.main.projectionMatrix` Then on the server I just set the matrices with uniforms as you can see in the shader code. So I wouldn't expect any errors there, but you never know. Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it.

Comment: I checked the implementation of the camera and the zooming indeed works by moving the position along the z-axis. But I still don't understand why this would cause a problem, since I use the same matrices for calculation. So shouldn't the server have the same holes in it?